# Turn this inefficient code appending columns to multiple dfs into a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the below code which appends a year column to each of my respective dataframes. I assume this would use a for loop, but since the year is different each year, I'm unsure how to do it.

```
hic_dfs = [hic15,hic16,hic17,hic18,hic19]

hic15['year']=2015
hic16['year']=2016
hic17['year']=2017
hic18['year']=2018
hic19['year']=2019
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create a list of values then zip them and assign `for a,b in zip(hic_dfs,[2015,2016,2017,2018,2019]): a['year'] = b`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ye = 2015
for idx, elem in enumerate(hic_dfs):
    elem["year"] = ye + idx
```

Comment: `for year, elem in enumerate(hic_dfs,2015):
    elem["year"] = year`?